# Как понять что ScrollView идет вверх или вниз не повторяя вызов слушателя?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть ScrollView и есть вот такой слушатель

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int iX, int iY, int iOldX, int iOldY)
{ 
if (mOnScrollListener != null)
    {
        mOnScrollListener.onScrollChanged(this, iX, iY, iOldX, iOldY);

        if (iY >= iOldY) {
            mOnScrollListener.onGoDown();
        } else {
            mOnScrollListener.onGoUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том что как только я делаю скролл вниз(к примеру) то метод `onGoDown()` вызывается раз 100 и это логично я согласен

Какое условие сделать чтоб этот метод был вызван только один раз если юзер делает скролл вверх и один раз если вниз

Comment: Нужно ставить флаг, что данный скрол пользователя обработан и не вызывать больше ваш метод. Но проблема в том, когда снимать этот флаг. Ведь пользователь может поставить палец и скролить вверх вниз, а может свайпнуть и отпустить. В общем, зависит от того, какое поведение нужно именно вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего надо держать два флага

```
boolean isScrollDown, isScrollUp;

 if (iY >= iOldY) {
            if(isScrollDown)
              return;

            mOnScrollListener.onGoDown();
            isScrollDown = true;
            isScrollUp = false;
        } else {
            if(isScrollUp)
               return;

            mOnScrollListener.onGoUp();
            isScrollDown = false;
            isScrollUp = true;

        }
```

Это на вскидку